# How to split a string before calling another constructor

Tags: java, constructor

I try to reuse my constructor like this:

```
    public final long x;
    public final long y;
    public final int level;
    private final int hash;
    public final Point tileCenter;

    public TileCoordinate(long x, long y, int level) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.level = level;
        this.hash = Objects.hash(x, y, level);
        this.tileCenter = getTileCenter();
    }

    public TileCoordinate(String key) {
        String[] bits = key.split("-");
//      this.level = Integer.parseInt(bits[0]);
//      this.x = Long.parseLong(bits[1]);
//      this.y = Long.parseLong(bits[2]);
        this(Long.parseInt(bits[0]),Long.parseLong(bits[1]),Integer.parseLong(bits[2]));
        this.hash = Objects.hash(x, y, level);
        this.tileCenter = getTileCenter();
    }
```

Since I don't want to write `this(Integer.parseInt(key.split("-")[0]),Long.parseLong(key.split("-")[1]),Long.parseLong(key.split("-")));`, what are my options?

Comment: Would you mind clarifying what *`since i don't want to repeat key.split for every parameter`* means? You only have one parameter correct?

Comment: no, i mean i dont want to write `this(Integer.parseInt(key.split("-")[0]),Long.parseLong(key.split("-")[1]),Long.parseLong(key.split("-")));`

Comment: Is that because the call to `this` must be the first statement in a constructor, if it exists?

Comment: yes thats the problem

Comment: How about a static factory method instead?

Comment: I suppose you could have a `setParam()` method to do exactly what your constructor does without it being a constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call to `this()` or `super()` must be the first statement in the constructor. One way to fix it would be to convert the second constructor into a  [Factory Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern):

```
public static TileCoordinate parseTitleCoordinate(String key) {
  String[] bits = key.split("-");
  long x = Long.parseLong(bits[0]);
  long y = Long.parseLong(bits[1]);
  long level = Long.parseLong(bits[2]);
  return new TitleCoordinate(x, y, level);
}
```

This would allow to keep the fields `final`.

Comment: Why `super()` is needed?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're only doing this line `String[] bits = key.split("-");` to avoid having to call it 3 times in the deferred constructor call to `this()`, which, if it exists, must be the first statement in a constructor.

Instead of delegating to a constructor for the actual field assignment, delegate to a `private` method that handles the field assignments.

```
public TileCoordinate(String key) {
    String[] bits = key.split("-");
    init(Long.parseInt(bits[0]),Long.parseLong(bits[1]),Integer.parseInt(bits[2]));
    this.hash = Objects.hash(x, y, level);
    this.tileCenter = getTileCenter();
}

private void init(long x, long y, int level) {
    // assign to fields here
}
```

Make sure it's `private` so it can't be overridden, where leaking `this` would become a problem.

You may also want to verify that `bits` has 3 elements before continuing.

Comment: But the fields are final, forgot to tell this

Comment: Well now that you've revealed that your fields are `final`, this won't work.  In that case, a factory method would be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Could overload an init method:

```
  public TileCoordinate(long x, long y, int level) {
      init(x, y, level);
  }

  public TileCoordinate(String key) {
      init(key);
  }

  private void init(String key) { 
      String[] bits = key.split("-");
      init(Long.parseLong(bits[0]),
           Long.parseLong(bits[1]),
           Integer.parseInt(bits[2]));
  }

  private void init(long x, long y, int level) { 
      this.setX(x);
      this.setY(y);
      this.setLevel(level);
  }
```

This maintains single-responsibility. Only the 2nd init method is calling the setters, the rest are delegating.